# Options for .Net Maui Authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, maui

Currently I have an application that is running asp.net MVC 5 utilizing Owin.IAppBuilder for authentication. This was the standard authentication method when building mvc applications. My current auth method connects to a SQL database and uses the standard aspNetUsers table method.

I am looking to start building a .net Maui mobile app. I would like to allow existing and future users of my MVC 5 application to authenticate with the .net Maui mobile app.

I researched many options but unsure the correct methods to start implementing. Does anyone have suggestions on what Path I should take?

Comment: didn't you already post this?

Comment: Re-worded the question due to your request of using the "best" word in the post. I didn't want to be off-topic like you mentioned. All I am looking for is some guidance on where to start looking. Maui is very new to me and the forums it seems like.

Comment: "Does anyone have suggestions..." is still not very on-topic for SO, especially without any concrete requirements to guide us.  Try using "xamarin" instead of "maui" when searching and most anything you find should be applicable to both.